Происхождение выражения «как два пальца обоссать»
Когда возникло выражение «как два пальца обоссать», и почему оно именно такое? Обоссать можно любое количество пальцев, и не только пальцы.  Почему именно два пальца?

Потому что 2 самое простое число, а один палец не говорят.

Ну а что может быть проще чем обоссать пальцы? Обоссать забор? Так его надо найти. Обоссать ноги? Так их и так две, не получится подчеркнуть простоту. Обоссать штаны? Так они одни, не получится вставить двойку.

Обоссать все 5 пальцев проще.  Или всю кисть руки.  Или предназначенный для этого унитаз.

Еще раз, проще то проще, но не получится воткнуть "два", подчеркивающее арифметическую простоту

Один - случайность, два - закономерность, наиболее простая последовательность событий, повторение.
